# Could not load type with VlabsMediaBundle in Symfony (Image Upload)

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

I followed this HowTo: [VlabsMediaBundle](https://github.com/V-labs/VlabsMediaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-bundle-setup-and-usage.md) and everthing worked, besides step 4.
I get an error saying:

> Could not load type "vlabs_file"

My `ModuleType.php`:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;


class ModuleType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
    $builder
        ->add('image', 'vlabs_file', array(
            'required' => false
        ));
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you use Symfony**3**?

Comment: I do, and I know it should look sth like `XXXType::class` instead of `vlabs_file` but I don't know how

Comment: Try with `\Vlabs\MediaBundle\Form\Type\FileType::class`